# Missing mouse cursor in x2go client when using Gnome session type

Tags: gnome, 20.04, x2go, x2goclient

Both the x2go server and x2go client are running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

When connecting from x2goclient client and specifying to use XFCE as the session type, the mouse is visible over the display area of x2go client after logging in and obtaining an X session from the server.

However, if connecting from x2go client and specifying to use Gnome as the session type, the mouse pointer is not visible at all over the display area of x2go client after logging in and obtaining and X session from the server.

---

Now just found:
https://bytexd.com/x2go-ubuntu/#installing-gnome-doesnt-work-with-x2go

.. and it says Gnome does not work with x2go. However, I have not been able to find anything official if this is really the case.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the official documentation stating what are the compatible Desktop Environments: https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat

.. and Gnome 3.36 which Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses is not supported.

> GNOME 3.12 and later: TBD, but probably not compatible. Using GNOME 3.12 and later with X2Go is not recommended.

Probably explains the missing mouse cursor when using Gnome